# incremental load of warehouse; updating dimension tables

Tags: mysql, data-warehouse

I'm trying to figure out how to incrementally load my fact and dimension tables as data come into our system.

Is there any simpler way than:

- dim_id = select id from dim_table where dim_table.value='dim value';
- if rowcount == 0 -> insert into dim_table ...
- insert into fact(dim, measure) values(dim_id, 23131)

if i got 10 dimensions the loading gets rather cumbersome

Comment: What's the `23131` all of a sudden? :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need them to be incremental ? Can't you use a UUID ?

I do not understand why you need a dim_table.

If you are doing a Star Schema, this is how you can make it work

```
Fact_table
----------
time_id          character(36)
geographic_id    character(36)
measure          whatyouwant

Dim Time
--------
time_id    character(36) (That matches the time_id inside your fact table)
...
...

Dim Geogrphic
-------------
geographic_id character(36) (that matches the geographic_id inside your fact_Table)
....
....
```

When you fill up your dimensions tables generate a uuid for your dimensions.
When you fille up your fact table, lookup into your dimension tables so you can get the uuid associated with this value.

Edit : I think that might help you http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: The dimension tables and the fact tables are both filled at the same time, based on the input to the system.   So when you receive a data item you do not know if there's a row in the dimension table yet.

Comment: Ok but one must be filled before the other. Or do you mean an insert to the fact_table can be right after an insert into a dim table that itself will be after an insert to the fact_table again ? If that not the case, you should make your dimension fill themselves first. Question : Are you dimension defined on the fly too ? Or do you know the dimension you will have?

Comment: I will be ingesting transaction logs, and "customer ip address" is one dimension.  And it will be defined on the fly, yes.

Comment: Arf if you are making it on the fly I can't tell. But I don't understand why the structure of the dimension table will be defined on the fly? Can you just let me know what is the advantage

Comment: No sorry, the dimension itself is not defined on the fly.  It all comes down to; is there a simple way to check if a row exist in a table, if so, get the PK, otherwise insert a new row and get the new PK for that row?

Comment: I edited my answer. Take a look at it. If not try IF EXISTS IF NOT EXISTS

Answer (score 0):

In a standard star schema, dimensions are loaded before facts.
So, if there is an ETL process in place which runs in batches, the simplest solution is to try to run the batch more often. If you do need a real-time DW loading, the facts have to be delayed somehow, to make sure that dimensions are loaded first.

When it comes to off-the shelf solutions, you may look into stream-event processing. There are several commercial tools out there, but [**EsperTech**](http://www.espertech.com/) is open source. The system can be set-up as an ETL transformation that runs continuously. Think of an Kettle (Talend, SSIS, ..) transformation which keeps running.